# Can ZeroBrane windows have a dark theme without using OS's high-contrast theme?

Tags: darkmode, zerobrane

Just to clarify, I'm not talking about making the background of the editing frame or window dark via:

```
local G = ...

styles = G.loadfile('cfg/tomorrow.lua')('Zenburn') -- theme
```

I'm talking about making the background of the Project frame/window, Output window, the menu bar, etc., all dark too.

Is this possible to do without using Windows's high-contrast theme for everything?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, as it relies on wxwidgets to draw those windows and wxwidgets uses system-provided colors to draw them (without much if any user control).

I opened a [wxwidgets ticket that would implement re-configuring system colors](https://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/18614), but there hasn't been much movement on it.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. How does an app like Jetbrains's IntelliJ IDEA do it, then? Like, I don't have a high-contrast set on my Windows 10 or anything but IntelliJ IDEA is all dark for me, while ZeroBrane is bright. Or ... you mean that ZeroBrane depends on wxwidgets but IntelliJ iDEA, for example, doesn't? I think I understood something different in the beginning, and that's why I asked.

Comment: Right; I'm not sure where IntelliJ iDEA is getting the colors from, but as a library user, I'm limited to what wxwidgets provides. Many of the colors can be configured, but not all unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the issue, Paul.